# Async function without "await" keyword returns the "Uncaught (in promise) error"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am fairly new to asynchronous functions and had experimented with the following scenarios:

**Scenario A**

```
async function foo() {
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) =>  reject('2')); //Uncaught (in promise) 2
}
foo().catch(() => {})
```

**Scenario B**

```
async function foo() {}
foo().catch(() => {})
```

My question is ***why*** does the error message occur in Scenario A? Both scenarios implicitly return a resolved promise with the value of "undefined," but only the error message shows on Scenario A. I also read that a promise without .catch() specified will hide its error message, but it clearly does not do so in the above example. I have been stuck for over an hour and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `async` function. You would get this also with a plain `new Promise((_, reject) => reject())`. It is simple: that promise rejects, and there is no handler for it. That promise has nothing to do with the one returned by the `async` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning your `p2` promise from your function, therefore, there's no way for the caller to `catch()` the result of that promise.  And, in this particular example, there is no reason for your function to be `async` since you aren't using `await` and you aren't throwing and expecting that to be turned into a rejected promise.  So, your uncaught promise doesn't have anything to do with `async` here.

```
async function foo() {
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) =>  reject('2'));
   return p2;
}

foo().catch(() => {})
```

or remove the unnecessary `async` keyword:

```
function foo() {
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) =>  reject('2'));
   return p2;
}

foo().catch(() => {})
```

> My question is why does the error message occur in Scenario A? Both scenarios implicitly return a resolved promise with the value of "undefined," but only the error message shows on Scenario A.

Because you're creating a promise `p2` and then doing nothing with it.  It isn't connected at all to the return value of `foo()` or to the promise that is automatically returned from the `async` function `foo`.  It's just orphaned there by itself and thus nobody catches its error.

> I also read that a promise without .catch() specified will hide its error message, but it clearly does not do so in the above example

You'd have to show us the context in which you read that because by itself that is not correct.  A rejected promise where that rejection is never caught will cause a warning.

---

If you `await` your `p2` promise, then the `await` is tied to the promise that the `async` function returns and that will work properly.  So, this will work:

```
async function foo() {
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) =>  reject('2'));
   await p2;
}

foo().catch(() => {})
```

The `await` will see the rejection.  That will then cause the promise that the `async` function returned to reject and the caller will see that rejection and your `.catch()` will catch it.  Without the `await`, this is just an orphaned promise.  `async` functions don't connect to all rejections inside them - they only connect to rejections that are awaited or are directly returned.

Comment: thank you for the highly insightful explanation. Could you explain one more scenario taken from MDN: async function foo() {
   const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('1'), 1000))
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('2'), 500))
   const results = [await p1, await p2] // Do not do this! Use Promise.all or Promise.allSettled instead.
}
foo().catch(() => {}) // Attempt to swallow all errors...

Comment: In the "results" variable, why does the error message occur for p2 if the asynchronous function is currently handling p1?

Comment: @user504557 - It's pretty hard to follow and comment on multi-line code in comments.  It sounds like this is perhaps a new question.  If you post it in a new question and drop a link to that question in a comment here, I'll take a look.